# stateChanged for ChatStateListener get called only once

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, asmack

I am using asmack to create xmpp client for android. I am using ChatStateListener to implement typing status in the chat between 2 users. I am facing this problem where stateChanged only gets called once. If I close the chat and create it again then stateChanged gets called once but not after that. I am not sure what is the problem. Please help me with this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you look-up the [Asmack lib](https://github.com/zewt/smack/blob/master/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ChatStateManager.java) then you can see method
>   `updateChatState(Chat paramChat, ChatState paramChatState)` will check
>   whether your current state are same as old state , if yes then that
>   method return false and this is the reason why you are not getting
>   callback every time .

For more info you can checkout this SO answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28425937/501483